# Does facebook have a public search API yet?

Tags: facebook, rest

I can't seem to find the definitive word out there of the facebook search api: the api that allows you to search public status updates and comments/posts (there is a web interface for all logged in users for this at the moment).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use the Facebook graph API :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

look for the searching section,

QUOTE from fb:

**Searching**

You can search over all public objects in the social graph with https://graph.facebook.com/search. The format is:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE
We support search for the following types of objects:

All public posts: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post

- People:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user
- Pages:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page
- Events:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event
- Groups:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group
- Places:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000
- Checkins:
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin

You can also search an individual
   user's News Feed, restricted to that
   user's friends, by adding a q
   argument to the home connection URL:

- News Feed:
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=facebook

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have already given up searching for this on their API ref page :)

Comment: Does using this API require registration of some sort? Or do you just use it just like that , without doing anything special?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes you need to register your fb application in developers.facebook.com to get your secret key

Comment: so it's not quite public, and anytime they wish, they can shut down the service specifically for your app.

Comment: i also used facebook graph api search for searching people by name, but when i compared to facebook search the list order is different and some users is missing. because they don't allow public search. but when i using facebook it shows all users. how to solve this issue?

Comment: Post April, 2013 this no longer works. "Search for application will no longer be supported." - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: the results provided but the graph api, aren't the same of the search in website. does someone knows about it?

Comment: I have checked it , Is this api Working Now ?

Comment: The graph search API search only NAMES, not content of posts

Comment: is this working for you guys? I can't search pages anymore.. it gives me an empty array.

Comment: It's not working anymore since April 4th 2018 for: event, group, page, user

Comment: @all - searching any entity using facebook graph api is no longer supported.

Answer (score 18):

Facebook Public Post search is no longer available in Graph API v2.0:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: User, Page, Event, Group, Place & Checkin search still seem to still work fine in v2.0 w/ the same format as the accepted answer with the /v2.0/ inserted. The Newsfeed - /me/home?q=x endpoint however is also no longer available in addition to Post search, for clarification.

Comment: I can confirm ^, but they seem to be removed it from the docs

Comment: The link doesn't contain  V2.0 details any more

Comment: That's correct. The API v2 has been deprecated on August 7, 2016

Answer (score 4):

Better way is using [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

-> Search any term using facebook php sdk.

```php
$mySrch = $facebook->api('/search?q=YOUR WORD&type=TYPES');
```

THERE ARE VARIOUS TYPES, you can search:

1. post
2. user
3. event
4. group
5. place
6. checkin

Comment: this is the same answer as above, it's just that the above it more general.
also your answer could be considered wrong since the user didn't specify that they want to use php

Comment: Post search is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

The search according to "type=user" type="event" type="group" type="page is deprecated now. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4