# Is there an official Facebook Graph Search API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is possible to search profiles,pages,groups and events by keywords in one url in facebook graph api?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the graph search that was announced recently and is currently available to some users. It is not available as some sort of API. However, you can use search API described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263287/does-facebook-have-a-public-search-api-yet)