# Has the Facebook graph search API been removed in Graph API version 2.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I can use the Facebook Graph API successfully (within my iOS app) for several calls but I'm trying to use it for searching.

I implemented the url after googling and getting many hits, i.e. [Does facebook have a public search API yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263287/does-facebook-have-a-public-search-api-yet).

I can use the search API from a browser and get results, however it doesn't work from within my app.

So I had a look at the Facebook graph API reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0

and search isn't listed there. Has it therefore been removed?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: What type of search are you referring to? Post search was removed in v2.0 of the API - most other types still exist

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Facebook has just taken down public post search in Graph API v2.0 so you won't be available to do that anymore.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading under section Graph API "Public post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)"